# How to use "bind" keyword instead of ">>=" operator in Haskell

Tags: haskell, monads

I'm trying to understand Haskell monads and wrote this test program, which compiles and works as expected:

```
divide :: Int -> Int -> Either String Int
divide _ 0 = Left "Divide by zero error
divide numerator denom = Right (numerator `div` denom)

processNumsMonadically :: Int -> Int -> Either String Int
processNumsMonadically n d = divide n d >>= \q -> return (q+1)
```

When I try using the word `bind` instead of the `>>=` operator in the latter function definition:

```
processNumsMonadically n d = bind (divide n d) (\q -> return (q+1))
```

I get the error:

```
Not in scope: 'bind'
```

What is the correct way to use the word `bind`?

Comment: Note that `bind` is not a keyword. It's a name people use to refer to `>>=` operator. You can define `bind = (>>=)` if that helps.

Comment: Thank you for correcting me.  I should have known it was a name, not a built-in keyword.  I'll edit my post (and leave this comment if you leave yours).

Comment: Indeed almost nothing is a keyword in Haskell (`class`, `instance`, `type`, `newtype`, `data`, `case`'`of`, `do`, `if`'`then`'`else`, `let`'`in`, `where`: those are pretty much all that can occur in the actual code part. Plus a few more which are only used in the module header, and a few from GHC extensions – the full list [is here](https://wiki.haskell.org/Keywords).) All other _words_ are simply names of functions/actions, defined in some library (if not in your own code); you can use [Hoogle](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/) or [Hayoo](http://hayoo.fh-wedel.de/) to find them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This isn't a part of Prelude; it resides in [`Control.Monad.Extra`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/monad-extras-0.5.9/docs/Control-Monad-Extra.html), a part of `monad-extras` package.

---

However, you can call operators in prefix manner (like named functions) easily:

```
processNumsMonadically n d = (>>=) (divide n d) (\q -> return (q+1))
```

You could also just use `do` notation:

```
processNumsMonadically n d = do
    q <- divide n d
    return (q+1)
```

But while we're at it, I'd write using a Functor:

```
processNumsMonadically n d = fmap (+1) (divide n d)
```

or Applicative syntax:

```
processNumsMonadically n d = (+1) <$> divide n d
```

You could also `lift` the `+1` to avoid the need for `return` and the lambda.

---

As a personal style remark, `bind` used as a word isn't idiomatic, and IMHO you shouldn't use it.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and advice.  FYI, I wasn't planning to use `bind` as a word in programs, just as an intermediate step when teaching monads.  I appreciate the `do` syntax.

Comment: @espertus sorry, can't help it; I just keep seeing the more and more ways  to write the function :)

Comment: Thanks for the improvements, although I'm just trying to stay *one* step ahead of my students. :-)